# Laravel - Get up to date model attribute in a collection each

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looping through a collection and accessing an attribute on the model for the user of the collection item.

```
$advancedBookingsQuery = Booking::query();
$advancedBookingsQuery = $advancedBookingsQuery->where('type', 2)
    ->with('staffMember.user');
$advancedBookings = $advancedBookingsQuery->get(['id', 'requested_booking_time', 'estimated_booking_time']);

foreach ($advancedBookings as $booking) {
    $barberQueueLength = $booking->staffMember->user->currentQueueLength;
    $booking->update(['estimated_booking_time' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes($barberQueueLength)]);
}
```

The currentQueueLength method runs some queries to get the length of total bookings that meet a requirement.

```
public function getCurrentQueueLengthAttribute()
{
    // Calc length of all bookings with an estimated booking time value
}
```

The issue is that the currentQueueLength attribute is always returning the same value for each item in the collection.

Is there a way that I can get the attribute to be freshly called in each iteration of the collection ->each method? It seems to be just using the value when the $advancedBookings collection is gathered.

Comment: Per [Laravel Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), shouldn't `currentQueueLength` be `current_queue_length`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem just yesterday, instead of using

```
$booking->staffMember->user->currentQueueLength;
```

try using

```
$booking->staffMember()->first()->user()->first()->currentQueueLength;
```

Also try looking into the refresh method: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_refresh
I haven't personally tried it because the first solution solved my problem

Comment: `->get()` returns a `Collection`, so `->get()->user()` would fail trying to access the function `User` on a `Collection`, which doesn't exist...

Comment: my bad, should of have been using first, editing the answer with the correction

Comment: Which is fine, but `->staffMember` (without the parenthesis) would return `->first()` or `->get()` depending on whether or not the relationship is included as a `->with()` clause, and based on `hasOne`, `belongsTo`, etc etc; so you're still adding more steps than is required. The top syntax is correct (assuming the relationships are defined correctly) and less memory intensive, as extra queries are not run.

Comment: Yes, my idea was that the extra queries were intentionally run to refresh the relationship item, but I'm now thinking that the relationship models are not modified at all, and would have to see the currentQueueLength function in order to diagnose the problem

Comment: Agreed; I think there's more of an issue with the function itself than the way it's being called; unfortunately that was left out of the question for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Per [Laravel Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Change

`$booking->staffMember->user->currentQueueLength;`

To (snake_case)

`$booking->staffMember->user->current_queue_length;`